# VM cannot access network on new Hyper-V Host

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v-server-2016

I re-built an existing Hyper-V host server on Windows Server 2016 to move to a larger SSD RAID for storage (required OS re-install). The host itself is on the domain and accessible via RDP all looks well. I then copied a test VM to the host and it starts up, but has no network connectivity. I tried deleting and re-creating the virtual switch, but still no luck. The virtual switch is on NIC3, external network, and "allow management operating system to share this adapter" is unchecked. These settings are exactly how it was configured before and I am using the same NIC as before. I cannot ping the VM from the host, nor can the VM ping the gateway or any other IP on my network. Any ideas on what to look at?

Comment: Dumb question: Does the VM have a virtual NIC and is it connected to the virtual switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is the (real) switch port connected to NIC3 configured? Is it in trunk or access mode? Did you maybe miss a VLAN setting somewhere?

---

### Edit:

How many NICs do you have? Make sure you selected the right one in the virtual switch configuration.
The names can be misleading, because Hyper-V uses the device names instead of the friendly names; what you call "NIC3" might not actually be the third NIC in the device list.

Comment: I am  using a Meraki router and no VLan settings. I have never configured any of the ports on the router so are at defaults. I used the same procedures I did for my other Host. On my other host, after configuring the Virtual Switch, the only protocols checked on the NIC are "Microsoft LLDP Protocol Driver" and "Hyper-V Extensible Virtual Switch". On this host, the NIC protocols remain unchanged and I cannot select "Hyper-V Extensible Virtual Switch" even manually.

Comment: You can't enable "Hyper-V Extensible Virtual Switch" manually; the physical NIC is configured by Hyper-V when you bind it to a virtual switch. If the NIC still has the default protocols enabled and no "Hyper-V Extensible Virtual Switch", then Hyper-V didn't claim it.

Comment: See my edit about selecting the correct NIC.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe the problem was confusion created by the "(un)friendly names" displayed in the Virtual Switch Manager . I have Dell R620 servers with 4 NICs. For some bizarre reason NIC1 = "Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet #2", NIC2 = "Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet #3", NIC3 = "Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit", and NIC4 = "Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet #4". The adapter I thought was NIC3 was actually NIC2 and wasn't even plugged into the switch. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Been there, done that...